# Instantiate derived class properties of specific type from base class

Tags: c#

Instantiate derived class properties of specified type from base class

**Sample:**

```
public class TBaseModel{

    public TBaseModel(){
        //here i want to list all dervied class peoperties of type DbSet and Instantiate it here.
    }

}

public class TDataModel : TBaseModel
{
    public DbSet cars {set ; get ;}

    public TDataModel (){
        cars  = new DbSet(); // i don't want to do this
    }

}
```

Comment: A BaseClass should not know about their children. What problem are you trying to solve? This seems x-y to me.

Comment: you can access children properties by Assembly, and this way already working in entity framework .

Comment: Do you mean "by reflection"? If so, yes, you could do that. It's not usually a great idea though. Again, what problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes i mean reflection, i made my own framework and i want make auto instantiate derived class properties of specified type instead to do it manually for each dervied class .

Comment: Okay, so have you *tried* doing anything with reflection yet? I suggest you read the docs starting at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solutions is loop to all current class properties and create new instance based on property class type and set the new instance back to current class .

```
 public class TBaseClass
    {

    public TBaseClass()
    {

        Type thisClass = this.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] info = thisClass.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in info)
        {
            if (typeof(TDataModel).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
            {
                object newModel = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
                prop.SetValue(this, newModel, null);
            }


        }

    }
}
```